# добавить версионность к WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Есть сайт ASP Net MVC + Web.api

WebApiConfig содержит стандартную реализацию

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Возникла необходимость добавить версионность для работы мобильного приложения (по старому-напрямую и по новой версии- v1).

Есть контроллер:

```
public class MobController : ApiController{}
```

В котором есть метод(ы)

```
    [AcceptVerbs("GET")]        
    public HttpResponseMessage White([FromUri] mob1 mob){ 
****
}
```

Как это сделать? и как потом обратиться в контроллере к старой и новой версии?
т.е. нужно чтобы обращались к /api/mob/White?..(по старой версии), по новой версии /api/v2/mob/White?....

Comment: Версия может быть добавлена как в путь запроса, так и в параметр запроса и даже в заголовок запроса. Вам надо выбрать какой из вариантов вам подходит и его реализовывать

Comment: Честно скажу не совсем понял что вы имеете ввиду? у меня есть контроллер. 
public class MobileController : ApiController {}
В нем есть метод 
[AcceptVerbs("GET")]        
public HttpResponseMessage White([FromUri] mob1 mob)
мне на самом деле без разницы, хочется чтобы было правильно

Comment: [How to Version Your Service](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/wiki/How-to-Version-Your-Service).